# trying to run jmx as batch

Tags: file, batch-file, jmeter

I am have all the my tests in JMX(Jmeter tests), i am trying to run them but putting .bat file , but unable to do so, can some one let me know the easiest way ruuning the jmx in batch file , below is the file i created and trying to run , console application opens  & disappears  quickly .

@echo
cd D:\Softwares\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\JMeter -n -t D:\Reuters\Tests\SNS\VectorWise\Prop_data

\Jmeter_Testcases\propdata.smoke_QA.jmx -p d:\Reuters\Tests\SNS\VectorWise\Prop_data

\Jmeter_Testcases\Configs -l d:\jmeter\Daily{_time}.csv

echo today is %DATE% %TIME%

Comment: what is {_time}
hard to tell what you did wrong as you didn't use code lines. Mybe edit and format the question?
Mostly, check the paths and filenames.
Try running the batch file directly from a command prompt, so you can see if an error is displayed before closing the window

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have updated file paths correctly!

1) CD to Jmeter bin folder.

```
cd /path/to/Jmeter/bin
```

2) Then invoke Jmeter.bat

3) For -p option, you need to provide the file name with extension. like this,

```
-p d:\Reuters\Tests\SNS\VectorWise\Prop_data\Jmeter_Testcases\Configs\my.properties
```

Try this! It works fine for me!

```
@echo 
cd /path/to/Jmeter/bin
Jmeter.bat -n -t /path/to/JMX/file -p /path/to/property/file/name -l /path/to/save/result/file
echo today is %DATE% %TIME%
```